# Implementing a search with Elasticsearch using mysql data

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to Elasticsearch. I was using MySQL Full Text features till now.

I want my MySQL database as my primary database and want to use Elasticsearch alongside as a search engine in my website. I got several problems when thinking about it. The main problem is Syncing between MySQL database and Elastic search.

Some say to use Logstash. But even though I use it, would I need to write separate functions in my program to database transactions and Elasticsearch indexing?

Comment: Write a code in any language that will be called every 5(or n) seconds and that code will push the database changes to ESS. 
You'll push only those records which are recently modified within those x seconds. 
You can add a column in your table LastModifiedOn On Create UTC_Timestamp and on update UTC_timestamp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run periodic job doing full reindex and/or send individual document updates for ES indexing. Logstash sounds like ill-suited thing for the purpose. You need just the usual ES API to index stuff.